# ExtJS - Sync with a repeating ID

Tags: javascript, json, rest, extjs, store

I have a special use case where data come from a single table column containing a JSON. I'm loading the contents of this JSON into a ExtJS store and after changing or adding new items to the store I have to sync with the server.

The front end send a JSON array like this: `{"data":[{"name":"Tony","age":"10","id":"users.1"}]}`.

ExtJS sends the generated internal ID, is it possible to every time I sync I always send the same ID, lets say `10` instead of the generated ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a property in which ExtJS will send it's own generated id, and ignore it on the server side, and put your desired value (10) in the `id` field.

To do so, add this to your Model definition:

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
     clientIdProperty: 'clientId',
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I think you misunderstood, I don't want to take the ID from the server, I just want to send it from the front and the ID must be the same for all items in the store when they are sent to server.

Comment: Your problem is that ExtJS overrides you `id` with the generated data, right? If you set all your `id` fields in the models to let's say 10, and add the `clientIdPropery` as in the answer, you will have all the ids set to 10 when data arrives to the server.